# Save webbrowser control as image

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get webbrowser control as image. But when my code gives me a full screen image. I want to get only webbrowser image. How should I fix my code to get the right image?

```
Bitmap memoryImage;
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

     Graphics myGraphics = webBrowser1.CreateGraphics();
     Size s = webBrowser1.Size;
     memoryImage = new Bitmap(webBrowser1.Width,webBrowser1.Height, myGraphics);
     Graphics memoryGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(memoryImage);
     memoryGraphics.CopyFromScreen(webBrowser1.Location.X, webBrowser1.Location.Y, 0, 0, s);
     memoryImage.Save("C:\\Users\\Koo\\Desktop\\NaverMap.png");
```

Comment: Use webBrowser1.RectangleToScreen() to get the correct location and size you need for CopyFromScreen.

Comment: Could you help me doing this specifically? i'm very new to c#

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code - Which supported and does work, but not always works fine.

In some circumstances you will get a blank image screenshot(when there is a more complex html it loads, the more possible it fails)

```
using (var browser = new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser())
{
     browser.DocumentCompleted += delegate
     {
         using (var pic = new Bitmap(browser.Width, browser.Height))
         {
             browser.DrawToBitmap(pic, new Rectangle(0, 0, pic.Width, pic.Height));
             pic.Save(imagePath);
         }
     };

     browser.Navigate(Server.MapPath("~") + htmlPath); //a file or a url
     browser.ScrollBarsEnabled = false;

     while (browser.ReadyState != System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
     {
         System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
     }
}
```

Comment: my original code generates when i click a button. where should i put this code in?

Comment: This code is far too misleading, you can't assume that DrawToBitmap() can work for a WebBrowser.  Server.MapPath???

Comment: That's why I added comment in code to put the File path or URL. Ideally It is working if we provide the valid URL and browser ReadyState  goes to Completed.

Comment: @구민재 You can put the code from browser.DocumentCompleted delegate block into your Button Click event. imagePath would be the path of location for saving the image